# Surjective Continuous Map

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, compactness

I have been struggling to show that there does not exist a surjective continuous map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}$ such that the inverse image of any compact set is compact.

I know that such a function would map compact sets to compact sets. Are there any suggestions for solving this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: assume $K=\{x:f(x)=0\}$ is compact. Take $R>0$ such that $K\subseteq B_R=\{x:\|x\|\le R\}$. Then $B_R$ is also compact and so $f[B_R]$ is bounded, say contained in $[-N,N]$ for some~$N$. Take $a$ and $b$ with $f(a)=-N-1$ and $f(b)=N+1$.
Take a curve $C$ outside $B_R$ that connects $a$ and $b$ and show that there is a point on $C$ that maps to $0$.